# Return Custom JSP in Struts 2 without a Defined Result

Tags: struts2, struts

Is it possible to just return a custom JSP filename in a Struts action, which doesn't have a mapped Result?

Example:

```
public String doAction() throws Exception {
   return "myfile.jsp";
   // do not return a mapped result
   // return "success";
}
```

When I do so, I get the error

```
No result defined for action MyAction and result myfile.jsp
```

The reason is I'm developing a new flow where multiple actions can lead to a new special error page. But it would be a pain to patch the entire Struts-Config XML with the new result defined for every action! So I want to avoid that and just reference a JSP directly.

Comment: You can use a convention plugin. It defines a configuration for all jsp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Struts feature and tutorial could be used instead to solve your original issue:

1. [Global Results](https://struts.apache.org/docs/result-configuration.html#ResultConfiguration-GlobalResults)
2. [Exception Handling](https://struts.apache.org/docs/exception-handling.html)

Comment: Just an addition, for completeness, although as this is solved it is certainly overkill: It is possible to define an unknownresult handler. This can be used to define your own conventions. As your issue stems from an exception, this isn't required. But say you have the conventions handling something but then decided to come up with your own conventions in addition, conventions would first try to look up something sensible, failing that the unknown result handler would be invoked doing... well pretty much anything.